# No result of working db function

Tags: postgresql, cakephp-3.0

I had problem with my db function (postgres) in cakephp 3. It's really very strange because function working ok in select window pgAdmin but in cakephp i don't have result.
Here is my postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aqua.chart_def()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    c CURSOR FOR select '[''' || to_char(create_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')||''','||air_temp||']' def from aqua.measurements
          where create_date >= now() - interval '2' hour and create_date <= now();
    result text := '';
BEGIN
    FOR r IN c LOOP
      result := result||', '||r.def;
    END LOOP;
    return ltrim(result, ', ');
    --return '[''2016-06-02 13:39'',28], [''2016-06-02 13:42'',23], [''2016-06-02 13:49'',24], [''2016-06-02 13:52'',29]';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION aqua.chart_def()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

This function returns result: `['2016-06-02 13:39',28], ['2016-06-02 13:42',23], ['2016-06-02 13:49',24], ['2016-06-02 13:52',29]`.

The best part is if I comment line:

```
    return ltrim(result, ', ');
```

And component line with copied result from this function:

```
    return '[''2016-06-02 13:39'',28], [''2016-06-02 13:42'',23], [''2016-06-02 13:49'',24], [''2016-06-02 13:52'',29]';
```

Like above is working in cakephp. Whats going on? Result is the same in sql window.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class ChartsController extends AppController {
     public  $name = 'Charts';    
     public  $uses = null;
     public  $helpers = array('Html');

     function beforeFilter(Event $event)
     {
        $this->setChartDef();
     }

     public function index(){                       
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('default');
     }

    public function setChartDef()
    {
        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');     
        $results = $connection->execute('select t.text def from aqua.chart_def() t')->fetchAll('assoc');
        $this->set('chart_def', $results[0]['def']);
    }
 }
```

And view:

```
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>                                          
    <?php  echo $this->Html->script('excanvas.min.js');?>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php
    echo $this->Html->script(['jQplot/jquery.min.js', 'jQplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js', 'jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js', 'jQplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js']);
    echo $this->Html->css(['jQplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css', 'jQueryUI/jquery-ui.css']);
    ?>
    <div><?php print_r($chart_def); ?></div>
    <div id="chart_temp" style="height:500px; width:500px; margin:auto; "></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var line1=[<?php print_r($chart_def); ?>];
      var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart_temp', [line1], {
        title:'Temperatura',
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            }
        },
        series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
      });


    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I guess this is some cache issue, beacause is actually work but with no actual data.

Comment: you should try to debug it. What is $results after `$results = $connection->execute('select t.text def from aqua.chart_def() t')->fetchAll('assoc');` ? Do you have any error message?